# Resizing Large Logo In Drupal Theme

Tags: css, drupal-8

I am trying to customize a Drupal 8 theme to display a large size logo. What I mean is that I am trying to use a larger image so that the logo does not look rugged on high-resolution screens. Currently, when I insert a larger image, it blows up on the page. That is, somehow the theme displays it as-is. How can I modify the CSS to have the logo display as ~ 170 x 70px, even though it is actually a much larger image (ratio preserved).

Relevant HTML (Twig):

```
<div class="logo-and-site-name-wrapper clearfix">
  {% if site_logo %}
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home" class="site-branding__logo">
        <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
      </a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_name %}
    <div class="site-name site-branding__name">
      <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_slogan %}
    <div class="site-slogan site-branding__slogan">{{ site_slogan }}</div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.site-branding__logo {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 1em; /* LTR */
margin-bottom: 0.286em;
}
[dir="rtl"] .site-branding__logo {
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div id="page-container" class="page-container">

          <div id="header-container" class="header-container white-region">


                      <header id="header" role="banner" class="clearfix header fixed-width two-columns">
          <div class="container">
                        <div id="header-inside" class="clearfix header-inside">
              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="header-area">
                                            <div id="header-inside-first" class="clearfix header-inside-first">
                          <div class="region region-header-first">
    <div id="block-startupgrowth-branding" class="clearfix site-branding block block-system block-system-branding-block">


    <div class="logo-and-site-name-wrapper clearfix">
          <div class="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home" class="site-branding__logo">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/logo_Black_Large_1.png" alt="Home" />
        </a>
      </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.logo-and-site-name-wrapper .logo img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

or

```
.site-branding__logo img {
      width: 170px;
      height: 70px;
}
```

CHECK IN CODEPEN:

http://codepen.io/paolomioni/pen/gwqJQB

Comment: Can you paste a copy of the rendered HTML?

Comment: I have edit the question to include the HTML rendered.

Comment: With your HTML (and a different image, since I couldn't load the ones in your site), I've made it work in the Codepen. Check the link in my answer. The CSS is correct, if it doesn't work you've put it in the wrong plave or you have some cache that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to solve this issue:

**Option 1:** Use an SVG file for your logo. An SVG will look crisp at any resolution since its vector based. This is the recommended option.

**Option 2:** Upload an image double the outputted size.

So for your particular image, upload a 340x140 file and set the CSS to the following:

```
.site-branding__logo img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: The second option does not work (see comments to the other answer). I shall try Option 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.site-branding__logo img {
    width: 170px !important;
    height: 70px !important;
}
```